# actions-on-google/smart-home-nodejs where is the "home control"

Tags: google-assistant-sdk, google-smart-home

This step, I can't find the "Home Control" in the "Google Assistant" app, The deivce mean a Phone?, block in this step.
Thank you for any help.

```
Setup Account linking
1.On a device with the Google Assistant logged into the same account used to create the project in the Actions Console, enter your Assistant settings.
2.Click Home Control.
3.Click the '+' sign to add a device.
4.Find your app in the list of providers.
5.Log in to your service.
6.Start using the Google Assistant in the Actions Console to control your devices. Try saying 'turn my lights on'.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is something that is in your Home Control settings on the Google Assistant app on your phone.

`Google Assistant > Settings > Home Control > Add`